# HowTo OpenSSL feature in Netty 4.0.23(Error occurs like Can't find dependent libraries)?

Tags: openssl, netty

I was trying to use SSL feature in Netty 4.0.23, but failed until now.

The problem occurs like this(On runtime. In build time no problems occur).

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\heuser\AppData\Local\Temp\netty-tcnative4254708149416235536.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:193)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:39)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContext(SslContext.java:184)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContext(SslContext.java:85)
```

It seems like netty-tcnative4254708149416235536.dll file has some dependencies, but no clues anymore.

To fix the error and other errors I followed the instruction in http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html

1. Installed OpenSSL(http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
2. Put two APR files(libapr-1.dll, libapr-1.pdb) into 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin.'
3. Added the above path to $Path

As you can see, I've tested in Windows(x86_64).

Additionally, What I added in my pom.xml are,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections-maven</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.8</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.30.Fork2</version>
        <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```